# find bone vertices relation?

Tags: weight-painting

I've weight-painted my modell, but have problems with some vertices. I don't find the bones, which do the deformation of some vertices.

Is there a way to find and select vertices and see the weight, and with which bones it is linked?

Thanks

Michael

[image]

Comment: I don't think so but maybe someone knows, but I guess you know you can weight paint it with a Substract brush, or select the vertice in Edit mode and click Remove From All in the menu available on the right of the Vertex Groups list

Comment: Hi @moonboots, thank you for your tip. My problem is, that these vertices are attached to one bone, which I can't find. I have tested all bones, but non of all my bones changes these vertices. Hm?

Comment: perhaps share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/    if you Remove From All you won't find which bone but at least you will release the vertice from any influence

Comment: Hi all, my problem is solved with this weight paint tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_qUehBf6x0

Comment: can you please tell a little bit more? thank you